# Azure: .NET Framework (with EF code first) and Microsoft SQL Server sudden CPU spikes for certain queries

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, entity-framework

I have an application running in Azure. It has a .NET framework API deployed as an App Service, connected to a Microsoft Sql Server. The .NET framework app uses Entity Framework Code First to access the database.

Usually, the application runs smoothly. However, from time to time, one single endpoint becomes unresponsive (i.e. takes minutes to return an answer). This endpoint is doing a query, through EntityFramework, and retrieving just a few data points from the database. This is the code, executed for 2 to 8 sensors (does not make any difference):

```
  List<Measurement> result = CreateContext().Measurements
                .Where(m => m.MeasurementSeries.SensorInfoID == sensorId)
                .Where(m => m.MeasurementSeries.StartTime <= toTime && m.MeasurementSeries.EndTime >= fromTime)
                .Where(m => m.Time > fromTime && m.Time <= toTime)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Time)
                .ToList();
```

By looking at the metrics (from ApplicationInsight, too) I see no weird query being executed. I see the expected query, and the database compute utilization jumping to 100%.

The same query, executed from the same code, connected to the same remote database, but with the .NET Framework app running locally, takes less than a second and less than 1% compute from the database. When the query (eventually) finishes, the database compute utilization goes back to zero. The API compute utilization is very low, always. Executing the same SQL query directly to the database takes less than a second.

All other endpoints, some of which make heavier queries to the database, work fine.

I tried re-running the same query multiple times and from multiple sources, restarting, stopping and starting, re-deploying the application. Nothing happens. Last time, after half a day, it just started working again. This time it's been over a day, and nothing.

Do you have any pointer to where to look for the issue? If there are more information I can provide, please let me know, because I may have not thought about them and it can help me figuring out the problem, too.

Comment: so the Azure SQL Database is at 100% CPU for minutes if the suspect query is hanging slow?

Comment: The Azure SQL database is around zero by default. After the endpoint is invoked (and, hence, the query executed) it spikes to 100%, and after a few minutes (when the query is done), it goes back to zero. In "normal times", when the query goes smooth, it takes just a few % of the db CPU.

Comment: may be that's a case for the Azure Support Engineers, as they have the insights and you are paying for a managed DB solution. I guess you cannot share so much information as needed here

Comment: Do you have indexes on `SensorInfoId`, `StartTime`, `Endtime` for `MeasurementSeries`? 
Do you have a descending index for `Time` on `Measurements`? 
Have you investigated locking ? you can use [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql)

Comment: Sharing your [wait stats](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/wait-stats/) could also help.

Comment: If possible you could also [share the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts you just gave me a wonderful tool set. From there, I got to the "MAXDOP" issue on Sql Server, that was the problem. By bringing it to the suggested value (8), it works flawlessy. If you can write your suggestions as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: However, while the max DOP makes perfect sense, I would expect the same query to be slow independently from where it is executed from (local app, raw query, deployed app..). It's strange that, instead, I saw different behaviours.

Comment: Hi @Tu.ma, you also could make a summary and post it as answer. Thanks for Preben's help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @PrebenHuybrechts for providing the tools to solve it, in the question's comments. As suggested, for questions like this one, it's good to check [locks](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql), [wait stats and execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/).

**TL;DR**

Max DOP was set to infinite, and considering I am running Sql Server as serverless with scaling from 2 to 16 vCores, from time to time it did overkill parallelization for a very small query.

The following tools were useful for debugging: [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql), [sp_BlitzWho](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/).

**Long(er) version**

First, I used [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql) to see what was happening while waiting for an answer from the API. I called the endpoint, and run

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @get_task_info = 2
```

In the results, I found the *incriminated query*, hanging, with `wait_info` status of `CXPACKET`. From [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/) I figured that `CXPACKET` means that the master process is waiting for slaves to finish processing, and that Microsoft suggests to set Max DOP (*Maximum Degree of Parallelism*) to 8. [I did that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMSProcedure) using Microsoft SSMS and it worked like a charm.

I **guess** that, considering that the same query was used somewhere else to retrieve a bigger amount of data, it was optimizing it for that scenario, making it sadly slow for when the query was retrieving just few datapoints.

Comment: wow! didn't expect to be solved that fast!! can you also add all the helping tools and tips from Preben in your answer as reference?

Comment: I was even more surprised, it prevented some sleepless nights :) I added the tools in the top line, it's easier for people coming from Google.